# Internal intranet site to Sharepoint outside access

Tags: access

We have SharePoint 2010 and it is the enterprise edition installed on Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise.

**My question**. I have an application server that hosts many IIS websites which we can access Internally within our network. I have this SharePoint 2010 that is facing the internet and is accessible on the internet for all users who have an Active directory account. I want to have these internal websites on my Application server accessible inside SharePoint, is this possible. ?

I have done a Page viewer webpart and mapped the websites. It works internally but outside the company network it wont and says page cannot be displayed.

I need the basic configuration and will pick it from there further on or is it something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a publicly resolvable hostname for your other sites in IIS. Assuming your structure is somewhat like this:-

```
http://myinternetfacingsharepointsite 
http://internalapplicationsite:902
```

At present in a page viewer webpart inside your sharepoint site you are calling any page using the internal url `http://internalapplicationsite:902`. This is incorrect.

What you need is to have a domain name registered(ex - `xyzee.com`), mapped to the IP address of your server hosting the IIS site and add that domain name as a host header in the IIS bindings of the internalapplicationsite running on port 902.

So essentially the url you will be passing in the page viewer webpart is (`http://xyzee.com:902`). This will make pages from your internal IIS websites accessible outside your intranet.

Comment: Hi Arko Thanks for this input. So basically, I have to contact my ISP for requesting additional hostnames mapped to our IIS websites (which is in 10 applications) and have public IPs. ? I thought the purpose of sharepoint is to have multiple websites accessible within sharepoint. We cannot easily contact ISP every now and then and have IPs mapped to our every changing applications. Looking for a work around to this as this is not feasible.